# „Letzte 4 Wochen“ oder „Letzten 4 Wochen“

Tags: grammatical-case, adjective-ending

Eben kam in einer Gruppe Personen die Diskussion auf, ob es korrekt

> Letzte 4 Wochen

oder

> Letzten 4 Wochen

auf einem Button in einem Programm heißen muss. Als Muttersprachler hört sich für mich die Beschriftung „Letzten 4 Wochen“ falsch an, jedoch muss ich auch zugeben, dass sich in einem vollständigen Satz „… in den letzten 4 Wochen …“ korrekt anhört. Welche Form ist denn jetzt die korrekte?

Comment: Weder, noch, sondern:  "Die letzten 4 Wochen". Auf einem Button eher das, was der Natur des Programms entspricht, z.B.  `<button> << 4 Wo. </button>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Da die *letzten vier Wochen* immer ein bestimmter Zeitraum sind, bei denen es wenig sinnvoll ist, einen unbestimmten Artikel verwenden zu wollen, wird in normalem Sprachgebrauch wahrscheinlich ausschließlich eine Form mit *-n* auftauchen. Der Grund dafür ist die schwache Beugung des Adjektivs *letzte,* induziert durch das Vorhandensein des bestimmten Artikels. Vergleiche:

- heiße Wochen – die heiße**n** Wochen (Nominativ)
- heiße**r** Wochen – der heiße**n** Wochen (Genitiv)
- heiße**n** Wochen – den heiße**n** Wochen (Dativ)
- heiße Wochen – die heiße**n** Wochen (Akkusativ)

In deinem Beispiel handelt es sich aber um eine Beschriftung. Dort erwarten wir die kürzeste mögliche Form. Wenn dort nur die Wörter *letzte* und *Wochen* – zusammen mit der Ziffer *4* – stehen sollen, muss es artikel- und deswegen beugungslos *Letzte 4 Wochen* heißen.

Wenn allerdings mehr Kontext mitgegeben wird, ergibt sich fast immer die Form mit *-n.* Beispiele:

> Letzte 4 Wochen
>
> Die letzten 4 Wochen
>
> Ansicht der letzten 4 Wochen
>
> Änderungen der letzten 4 Wochen
>
> …

Answer (score 4):

In aller Regel würde ich Nominativ auf einem Button erwarten. Und das ist dann "Letzte 4 Wochen".

Wenn ein Label neben dem Button aber den Text "Ansehen der..." hat, so ist dies ein Argument für "Letzten 4 Wochen". Es hängt also nicht nur vom Button alleine ab, sondern auch vom Kontext.